# calculate relationship between cause and effect (rows/columns/delta etc.) on tableform

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I tried to enter this Excel (on the right of the picture) information to program.

[image]

following these codes has been used:

```
A = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}

g = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

coming Output "g" called

```
cycles = FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]

countLoopsWithVar[all_, var_] := Count[all, _?(MemberQ[Flatten[List @@@ #, 1], var] &)];
```

for example I count variable 2 with:

```
countLoopsWithVar[cycles, 2]
```

I can only visualize feedback loops and the number of variables with these codes:

```
TableForm[Map[{#, countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #]} &, Range[14]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"variable nr.", "feedbackloops AW"}}]
```

On the delta (∆) value: ∆∑ cannot enter "-" or "0" values, there I have lowest value “-9”. Above that we should add 10 (∆+10) for each ∆∑.

How can I feel the table futher with cause,effect,∆∑,product value etc.?

Comment: Don't use `TableForm` for anything that is NOT presenting/prettifying/displaying. Now, imagine for a second you are one of the other community members -- you don't have the specific domain knowledge, haven't spent time solving the problem, etc, now, read your question from top to bottom and tell me if it is an easy task. Edit our question to make it really a complete one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say:

```
effect = Total[A]
```

Then you can, for example, extend your TableForm like this:

```
TableForm[
  Map[
    {#, countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #], effect[[#]]} &, 
    Range[14]
  ], 
  TableHeadings -> {
    None, 
    {"variable nr.", "feedbackloops AW", "effect"}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The others ones can be done just like this. It may not be the best way to do this, but it is a way to do it with minimal changes to the code you already have.

---

The next one would be `cause`:

```
cause = Map[ Total, A ]
```

And then `deltaSum`:

```
deltaSum = cause - effect
```

Et cetera...